# Change text view value for all layouts using the same resource file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

I'm trying to change the value of a text view defined in an XML file for all the layouts that use the above file. The XML file serves as the header for all the pages and I am trying to display the username in the header file without manually having to set that value in each activity file.

```
textView textElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_id);
    String user_id_string = Integer.toString(user_id);
    textElement.setText(user_id_string);
```

From my understanding, you cannot change the actual value of the resource file and the above only changes the value for the specific layout. How can I go about this? Thank you!

Comment: What is "the above file"?

Comment: declare a string in your application class , and assign the value and then  use this value wherever you want in your whole project

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences can help you.

In the layout-activity where you get user ID, save the value to SharedPreference Variable.

In rest of the layout-activities, populate the value from SharedPreferences in onResume().

Answer (score 0):

You are right - there are no specific options in Android SDK to achieve exactly what you want.

But still you can solve this issue with simple encapsulation - just create base `ActivityWithHeader` class and implement setting of header there. And use it as parent for your others `Activities` which needs this logic.

Also from the context of your question I think you may find these links helpful:

[Re-using Layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

[Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)